# Getting a new array of dictionaries from an array of strings, for display in collection view

Tags: swift

Say I have an array of dictionaries like this:

```
[
  ["name": "Jack", "age": 20],
  ["name": "Molly", "age": 21],
  ["name": "Kyle", "age": 34],
  ["name": "Jenny", "age": 18],
]
```

And an array of Strings like this:

```
["Kyle, Jack"]
```

I want the array of dictionaries to be filtered using the array of strings so it ends up like:

```
[
  ["name": "Kyle", "age": 34],
  ["name": "Jack", "age": 20],
]
```

---

This is because I want to my collection view to only display items from the first array if their names are in the second array (the one with only strings). There are other collection views, each that will be filtered with different arrays of strings.

How would I do this?

I have tried doing something like:

```
if nameArray[indexPath.item] == dictionaryArray[indexPath.item]["name"] {
  //code for cell here
}
```

But it doesn't display the cells in the array of strings' order. It would do something like:

```
[empty cell] [Jack's cell]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `dictionayArray.filter({ nameArray.contains($0["name"] as! String) })`

Comment: @Kamran this works! but it doesn't leave it in the order of `nameArray`

Comment: yeah then i think you should do as mentioned in the answer with map!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
arrStrings.map { str in
    return arrDicts[arrDicts.index(where: { dict in
        if let name = dict["name"] as? String {
            return name == str
        }
        return false
    })!]
}
```

It's not very efficient, but because you want to maintain the order, I think searching through the array of dictionaries is necessary.

This assumes that dictionaries with names specified by the array of strings exist. If they might or might not exist, you can try:

```
arrStrings.compactMap { str -> [String: Any]? in
    guard let index = arrDicts.index(where: { dict in
        if let name = dict["name"] as? String {
            return name == str
        }
        return false
    }) else { return nil }
    return arrDicts[index]
}
```

Comment: doing: `arrStrings.map { str in
            return arrDicts[arrDicts.index(where: { ($0["name"] as! String ) == str })!]
        }`
It keeps crashing with `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @sinio Ah I didn't realise you have an integer value in there.  Well `$0["name"]` can be a non-string, so you should not use `as!`. Use `as?` and handle the optional.

Comment: I don't have an integer value, `name` is always a String :) The new code still returns the same error :(

Comment: Ah ignore the top comment, I got it to work! I was using `name` rather than `Name`... Sorry for the hassle! Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: @sinio Your array of string should be `let arrStrings = ["Kyle", "Jack"]`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, we can use a `compactMap(_:)` approach similar to the one used in [@Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51462913/4573247), but instead:

- Making use of the [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first) method of `Array` rather than [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex) (previously named `index(where:)`)
- Making use of `Optional`'s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) method to conditionally perform the `name` (`String`) predicate

Using the above, we may compute the filtered array of dictionaries (ordered according to the ordering of the array of `String` names) as:

```
let filteredAndOrderedDicts = arrStrings.compactMap { name in
    arrDicts.first { dict in
        (dict["name"] as? String).map { $0 == name } ?? false
    }}

print(filteredAndOrderedDicts) // [["name": "Kyle", "age": 34],
                               //  ["name": "Jack", "age": 20]]
```

I believe `first(where:)` has better semantics than `index(where:)` / `firstIndex(where:)` for this given problem, whereas the use of optional binding (`guard let` / `if let`) vs `Optional`'s `map(_:)` is matter of preference (clarity vs brevity, perhaps).

---

In the example above, the input used is according to:

```
let arrDicts = [
    ["name": "Jack", "age": 20],
    ["name": "Molly", "age": 21],
    ["name": "Kyle", "age": 34],
    ["name": "Jenny", "age": 18],
]

let arrStrings = ["Kyle", "Jack"]
```